# PHP Time Check if Post is Older Than Six Months

Tags: php, time

I have, on my blog posts, the date when it was published and when it was updated (if it was updated). I need to add another control which checks if the post published or updated date is older than six months.

In the example below, I'm checking for "older than 1 hour" just to see if anything happens or not.

If so, display a DIV-tag with information (I will close the PHO and do a normal `<div class=""></div>`).

So, what I need is this: if the post does not have an "updated_on" date, calculate based on the "published_on" date and if the post does have an "updated_on", calculate based on that.

In other words, it first need to check if there's an "updated_on" and if not, use the "published_on" date.

This is my code:

```
<div class="published">

    Published on: <time datetime="2021-02-24T21:05:55+00:00"><?=date('jS \o\f F \@ H:i', strtotime($post['published_on']))?> (<?=time_elapsed_string($post['published_on'])?>)</time><br>

        <?php if ($post['published_on'] != $post['updated_on']): ?>

            Updated on: <time datetime="2021-02-24T21:05:55+00:00"><?=date('jS \o\f F \@ H:i', strtotime($post['updated_on']))?> (<?=time_elapsed_string($post['updated_on'])?>)</time>

        <?php endif;

          if ($post['published_on'] || $post['updated_on'] > 1 hour ) {

            echo 'Old Post!';
        }
    ?>
    
</div>
```

Problem is, I'm getting a Parse error saying: "P`arse error: syntax error, unexpected 'hour' (T_STRING)`"

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: That's because `1 hour` is not a valid PHP constant.  You can use `strtotime` to convert both values to time values (which are in seconds).  If `time() - strtime($post['updated_on'}) > 3600`, then it's older than an hour.

Comment: And by the way, your second `if` statement doesn't do what you think.  What that says is "if published_on is not empty, or updated_on is greater than an hour".  Since we know `published_on` is not empty, that will always be true.  I think you want to remove that, so you only check `updated_on`.

Comment: Thank you @TimRoberts, that both informed me and helped me a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: @TimRoberts any ideas on how to format the below code from LovingGarlic into a working example or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASSUMING every record has both a "published_on" date and an "updated_on" date, you can skip checkin the "published_on" date for your age check.

```
<div class="published">
<?php
if( !empty($post['updated_on'] )
    $age = $post['updated_on'];
else
    $age = $post['published_on'];
?>
    Published on: <time datetime="2021-02-24T21:05:55+00:00"><?=date('jS \o\f F \@ H:i', strtotime($post['published_on']))?> (<?=time_elapsed_string($post['published_on'])?>)</time><br>
        <?php if ($post['published_on'] != $post['updated_on']): ?>
            Updated on: <time datetime="2021-02-24T21:05:55+00:00"><?=date('jS \o\f F \@ H:i', strtotime($post['updated_on']))?> (<?=time_elapsed_string($post['updated_on'])?>)</time>
        <?php endif;
          if (new DateTime($age) < new DateTime('-6 months') ) {
            echo 'Old Post!';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, every post has an "published_on" date, but not every post has an "updated_on" date. So.. in a way, I need to check if the "updated_on" exists first and if not, calculate based on "published_on" and vice versa if "updated_on" exist.

The time to check for in reality is 6 months. Any suggestions on how to that? I apologize for my question not initially covering that.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I learned from that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the comparison:

```
if($post['published_on'] < new DateTime('-1 hour') || new DateTime($post['updated_on']) < new DateTime('-1 hour')) {
    //... do stuff
}
```

It should work similarly for most human readable strings like "-1 month", "+1 year" etc.

You can read more about [PHP DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick. You have both helped me a lot.

Comment: Using that example did not work as it shows "post old" no matter what date I put in. Any ideas?

Comment: This seems to work, but is that doing it right?

`if ( new DateTime($post['published_on']) < new DateTime('-2 weeks') || new DateTime($post['updated_on']) < new DateTime('-2 weeks')) {`

Comment: Yes, that would be it. The first part of the conditional also needs to compare. I'll update accordingly